Make a shape on a GraphicsPath C#
I'm trying to make this shape, but i don`t know how to do it. I only have the coordinates of the bottom left corner.
(https://i.sstatic.net/mxyiGUDs.png)
My task is to make a mini version of paint, where you can create this shape using the mouse starting from its corner. But I can’t create the figure itself using the GraphicsPath.
I hope you can help me with this task.

It is really difficult to figure out what the problem is without any code examples or other details. You should not need to use GraphicsPath at all, a call to Graphics.DrawPolygon should be sufficient. But this will be highly dependent on your exact use case and circumstances.

I would enter in some code that you have and explain where your having issues.
